# Accessing an app's project files on the Android platform

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

So in my Eclipse android project I have a pdf file that I'd like to open, I looked up the standard address on the android developer's page and I came up with this pointer:

```
File file = new File("Android/data/com.alex.testing.app/res/raw/jazz.pdf");
```

where **jazz.pdf** is situated in `res->raw` in my eclipse project, 
and `com.alex.testing` is my package name.

Still, when I try `if(file.exists())` , the function returns false (on the emulator it goes to an else I've set up to display an error message)...

Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm really stuck with this :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to access resources from current application you can use something like,

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://<you package>/raw/<your_file.pdf>");
```

OR

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" R.raw.<your_file.pdf>);
```

But I have a doubt if you are trying to use this pdf file in your application then its OK, but If you want to view this file using any third party application then I think you can't do it.

**Because external application can't access application's package resources file.**

So better way it to put this file in `/asset` directory then copy it to any public access area then view that file from that path.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard), I'm trying to open the file with the Adobe reader app, but it gives me an error, "The file could not be opened.". Also, when I check with the fileviewer /sdcard/ , there's nothing there... what am I doing wrong? :-? Currently I'm using Yoram Cohen's code.

Answer (score 1):

put the file in assets folder and pick the file from there

Now use `Context.getAssets().open("jazz.pdf")` and pass the resulting `InputStream` into PDf parser library

Answer (score 0):

//if your are stored in SDcard your location would be

```
"data/data/com.alex.testing/res/raw/jazz.pdf"
```

//you read resources from raw folder thru the below code

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jazz);
byte[] reader = new byte[inputStream.available()];
```